# Migrate Exchange 2013 on Windows Server 2012 to Exchange 2019

Tags: exchange, exchange-2019

As direct migration from Exchange 2013 to Exchange 2019 is supported I thought there would be a direct and easy path to migrate. However while looking more closely I see that Exchange 2019 is not supported on a Domain Functional Level below Windows Server 2012R2.

All my servers are currently Windows Server 2012. Is there a way to migrate to Windows Server 2019 and Exchange 2019 without moving the current Exchange 2013 to Windows Server 2012R2?

Comment: Please check if the below info is helpful to you. Besides, I think some requirements of forest/domain function level also need to notice: **Forest and Domain Functional Levels**
(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/active-directory-functional-levels)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to move your Exchange 2013 server(s), you need to upgrade your ***Active Directory domain*** to FL 2012 R2; this means you need at least WS 2012 R2 *Domain Controllers*.

Exchange 2013 can keep running on the server(s) where it is now; you need to add newer Domain Controllers and remove the current ones, then upgrade the AD functional levels.

Comment: Thanks, I thought you had to upgrade all Windows servers to be equal to or higher than the functional level. My plan is to upgrade the  DCs to 2016 then move everything else to 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Microsoft official documentation **[Supported Active Directory environments](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/supportability-matrix?view=exchserver-2019#supported-active-directory-environments)**, Exchange 2019 only supports Windows Server 2016 and Windows Server 2012 R2(**AD forest functional level**), you could raise the current AD forest function level to windows 2012 r2, or add new DCs/GCs and upgrade the function levels to windows server 2016/2012 r2, instead of moving your Exchange 2013(Before performing these changes, please don't forget to backup your servers).